# Adding menu with description like mega menu

Tags: 7, routes

I would like to create a menu with a description of the menu like megamenu. My menu looks like the following model:

[image]

How can I create this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided, as defined in [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Ultimenu](http://drupal.org/project/ultimenu)

> Ultimenu is the UltimatelyDeadSimple™ megamenu ever with dynamic
>   region creation.
>
> An Ultimenu block is based on a menu. Ultimenu regions are based on
>   the menu items. The result is a block contains regions containing
>   blocks, as opposed to: a region contains blocks.

Screenshot

[image]
**Usage:**

1. Enable or install the module.
2. Visit admin/structure/ultimenu to manage the Ultimenu blocks, regions, a skin library and a few goodies.
3. Once a menu is enabled, dynamic regions will be available to toggle. Only enabled regions (based on enabled menu items) will be visible at block/ context admin.
4. Visit admin/structure/block to assign the "Ultimenu: Menu name" block into header, sidebar, footer or navigation region, except Ultimenu regions.
5. Add other blocks to the Ultimenu regions.

Comment: Is it ok to use in production site ?

Comment: @SKM see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try TB Mega Menu, it's got very nice user interface (WYSIWYG) and also multiple built-in styles.

http://drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu

Answer (score 1):

You can use OM Maximenu to add description or block or menu inside menu.its quite simple and best to add like your design

http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu